# Magento 2 - How to redirect customer to specific URL after login with loginById?

Tags: magento2, redirect

I need to redirect the customer to a certain URL from a observer after I log him in with `loginById`.

How can I redirect?

Comment: If observer has controller object then easily redirect  from easly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with:

```
header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

Comment: exit, is not  right idea. Question where you have write  call `loginById` function? Controller  or model?

Comment: It is a observer for `controller_action_predispatch`

Answer (score 0):

You can get your current url in the observer using

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http

/**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
protected $_urlInterface;

/**
 * @var ResponseFactory
 */
protected $responseFactory;

public function __construct(
    ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    Http $request,
) {
    $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Get the current url

```
 $currentUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
```

Then just filter to get the condition of the current url you want

Then redirect anywhere you want

```
        $redirectUrl = "any url you want";
        $resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setRedirect($redirectUrl)->sendResponse('302');
```

NB: You can also retrieve the current action name it can be usefull

```
$fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
```

Comment: Can you please post the full classnames so I can test your code?

Comment: Sure : `use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;`

Comment: And what is `responseFactory` ? You miss many details

Comment: `use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory;`

Comment: Ok thx, now please edit your question and add these details.

Comment: I tried it, and it does not work. It does not redirect.

Comment: That's strange it should be working. Does it enter in your observer ? Do you have an error ? What are you returning in your execute method ? What's the tracking in your network when you execute ? From what i know there are no other way to redirect. Also what is your event ? I'm usually using this code with `layout_load_before`

Answer (score 0):

If you using `Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag` then you redirect from `controller_action_predispatch`

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    /**
     * execute function
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            if (MYCondition) {
                $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'YourUrlToRedirect');
            }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! Will try this out soon !